# How to Load images from FTP server in ImageView without saving on local storage?

Tags: android, ftp, imageview, ftp-client, androidhttpclient

I'm using FTP server to upload images for a social networking app. due to limitations of server with shared host. i've no problem with uploading, is there any way to download images from FTP Server, via HTTP ? because downloading each image on local storage first will be devastatingly slow and inefficient. And any suggestion about efficiency and memory management will be appreciated.

Comment: ummm. "download from ftp server, using http"? Huh?  http != ftp, and other than both protocols can transfer files/data, have absolutely nothing to do with each other.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately...

Comment: can i do something on server side ? like allowing images on FTP server to be downloaded through HTTP , its a standard web server with shared host and 50GB storage

Comment: its  private FTP server space on a web. domain @arkascha

Comment: This is a question you should ask your hosting provider, I'd say...

Comment: i mean username,password required for file access are totally under admin control, and all FTP traffic can also be monitored via admin panel.